# ASP.NET Chart: ToolTips on X and Y axis labels?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

Is it possible to set a ToolTip on the X and Y Axis labels on a databound chart? ToolTip exists in AxisY.CustomLabels, but I'm not sure how to make this work, or if there is an easier way.

Comment: you want show a tooltip if you hover X and Y Axis labels ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can,

to show tooltip on X-Axis

```
Chart1.Series["SeriesName"].LabelToolTip = "#VALX [#VALY]";
```

and on the Y-Axis

```
Chart1.Series["SeriesName"].ToolTip = "#VALX [#VALY]";
```

VALX --> X-axis value
VALY --> Y-axis value
there are many as well like
"#PERCENT"
"#AVG" etc etc

you can put anyother tooltip as you like.

Answer (score 1):

if you hover X and Y Axis labels you can see the x-axis value  and y-axis value at the tool tip.

```
      <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" ToolTip="#VALX(#VALY)""  >
        </asp:Series>
      </Series>
```